# Is there a django function to pass a object in database to the next redirected page in views in django

Tags: django, mongodb, redirect, view, djongo

I'm developing a project in Django in which I'm using a view(verify) to verify the student's login details. If the student is valid user then it'll redirect to a page(display.html) where all the details of that particular student is displayed. How can i pass the object containing the student details from verify view to the display.html??

Comment: please post your relevant codes

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link and update your question accordingly.